# Link array index to a variable

Tags: c#, .net, class, data-structures

Can I link/bind an array index to a variable, so that when the variable value change, it is automatically reflected on the array?

For example,

```
byte speed = 0x01;
Up       = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10, speed, 0x00, 0x00 };
Down     = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x08, speed, 0x00, 0x00 }; 
Left     = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, speed, 0x00 };
Right    = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, speed, 0x00 };
UpSpeed = 0x04;
```

I have 15 arrays like this.

I want when the speed value changes, Up and Down arrays will automatically reflect speed value.
I can currently do this by manually setting it like this:

```
public void SetSpeed()
{
    Up[4]   = speed;
    Down[4] = speed;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? 
The only way I can think of is implementing a setteer for speed and firing an evet then listening to that event and calling SetSpeed().

Comment: Not really, since `byte` is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) as opposed to a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). If an entry in the array at a specific index has a specific "function", maybe you want to create a structure for it, so you can at least do something like `Up.Speed = newSpeed; Down.Speed = newSpeed;` instead of having to know/remember, which index stands for what.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Make `speed` a property and update array value inside the setter:

```
byte _speed;
byte Speed
{
    get => _speed;
    set
    {
        _speed = value;
        Up[4] = value;
        Down[4] = value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can try with someething like this:

```
sealed class ByteArray
{
    readonly byte[] _source;
    readonly int _speedIndex;
    readonly Func<byte> _getSpeed;

    public int Length => _source.Length;

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index == _speedIndex)
            {
                return _getSpeed();
            }

            return _source[index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (index != _speedIndex)
            {
                _source[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ByteArray(byte[] source, int speedIndex, Func<byte> getSpeed)
    {
        // validate parameters, null check etc...

        _source = source;
        _speedIndex = speedIndex;
        _getSpeed = getSpeed;
    }

    public static explicit operator byte[] (ByteArray value) => value._source;
}
```

Basically a wrapper of the bytes array:

```
var up = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10, speed, 0x00, 0x00 };
var upWrapper = new ByteArray(
    source: up,
    speedIndex: 4,
    getSpeed: () => speed);
```

Comment: This can work but I have 15 arrays and that the value should be applied to. Won't this make the code ugly?

Comment: @David Let's see if I understand correctly, you have 13 arrays and all with the same value in position 4, right?

Comment: Code cannot always be beautiful. You could do something like _"_speed = Up[4] = Down[4] ....... = value;"_

Comment: @Alessandro D'Andria I have updated the post and wrote 15. Some of the indexes are on 4 and some on 5.  But its not an issue because I can make two variables one for index 4 and one for index 5.

PaulF imagine doing this for 15 indexes.

Comment: @David it's a strange requirement, maybe you have to change your data model.

Comment: @Alessandro D'Andria These are serial commands sent to cameras. Can you suggest a something to read to enhance my model?